# Why TextField returns null

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wencA.jpg)

I entered text in the TextField but it was not transmitted.

What should i do?
Please tell me.

The whole source code is in this [github](https://github.com/Ryosukekamimura/todoapp_by_flutter/issues), so please clone it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works for me, try a cold reset of the app. Stop the app fully and then run again.

Comment: Oh my god
I was able to run it on Android Studio as well
Is it because of Visual Studio?